# insert an array into database table

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to insert an array into a table within my database. I am dynamically adding inout fields so I can add team names. What I need to then do is insert those inputs into separate rows into the table but i either just get 'array' in the column or loads of empty fields.

Here is where I am at:

HTML for the form:

```
<div id="exercises">
    <div class="team">
        <input type="text" name="teamName[]" />
        <button class="remove">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery that handles the creating new inputs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#add_exercise').on('click', function() { 
    $('#exercises').append('<div class="team"><input type="text" name="teamName[]"><button class="remove">x</button></div>');
    return false; //prevent form submission
});

$('#exercises').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    return false; //prevent form submission
}); 
</script>
```

Then I am wanting to submit that to the database so here is where I am at with that (no security in place and am aware its open to SQL injection).

```
<?php 

// Config
include '../config.php';

// Get post data
$teamName = $_POST['teamName'];
$dashboardId = $_POST['dashboardId'];

// Check if the daashboard exists already
$sql = "INSERT INTO teams (team_name, dashboard_id) VALUES ('$teamName', '$dashboardId')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'good';
}

?>
```

If i do a var_dump n test submits I get the following:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "team 1" [1]=> string(6) "team 2" }
```

So I would like to insert a row with the name 'team 1' and another with the name 'team 2'

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am a little stuck...

Comment: When having a name like: `name="teamName[]`, then `$_POST['teamName']` will be an array, so you need to loop it and insert them one by one (or in a batch-insert-query).

Comment: How would I go about that sorry? I am a little confused, is there a little demo  you could show me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having a name like `name="teamName[]`, then `$_POST['teamName']` will be an array, so you need to loop it and insert them one by one (or in a batch-insert-query).

Example:

```
$dashboardId = $_POST['dashboardId'];

foreach($_POST['teamName'] as $teamName) { 
    if (empty($teamName)) {
        // Empty value, continue to next iteration instead
        continue;
    }

    //your db code 
}
```

You said that you are aware of the SQL Injection risk in your code so I won't go on about that. But I just want to note that if any of the names have an `'` character or ends with a `\`, your code will break, since it isn't escaped.

Comment: Thanks Magnus, that works perfectly. And I will do that now and make sure everything is set correctly.

Comment: @PhpDude Feel free to mark the answer if it works for you.

Comment: I just need to wait 3 mins :)